# Print Excel sheet with hyperlinks to PDF format while retaining links

Tags: ms-office, pdf, url

Hej,

I'm trying to print Excel 2011 sheet with hyperlinks into pdf format, but the output file doesn't retain hyperlinks.

Is there a way to preserve them in output format?

Comment: There is no Office 2010 on OSX. Did you mean 2011 ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, yes, right, 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than printing it to PDF try saving it to PDF.

Comment: I've tried to save it to PDF, but still no luck. Altough, if saved from Excel 2013 for Windows to pdf, hyperlinks are working.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2011 will keep the link when you save as PDF, but only if you give the full URL. I could not find a native way to retain embedded hyperlinks when saving to a PDF from Excel 2011.  However, there are a number of workarounds:

- If you have [Numbers](https://www.apple.com/mac/numbers/) (the Apple equivalent of Excel) you can upload your xls file and then save as a PDF from there.
- If you **don't** have Numbers, you can use an online conversion tool such as: http://www.zamzar.com/